# ADO.NET check if column name in selected columns

Tags: c#, sql, select, ado.net

This may be some trivial question but so far I could not get it (as I said I am sure that it is pretty simple, but I don't see it).

I am making a select with ADO.NET, something like this

```
SELECT col1,col2 from table1
```

I have few selects where the data I am selecting slightly differs. No I have built a function where I am retrieving the selected data(there are all the colums that occur in at least one select) and there is the problem. Since the data I select is not always the same I need to check whether the colum I am trying to get data from is in the select or not.

For example I have tried this, but it is not working(it always returns false)

```
private bool SpalteExistiert(FbDataReader Reader, string MyColumnName) 
{
    return Reader.GetSchemaTable()
       .Rows
       .OfType<DataRow>()
       .Any(row => row["ColumnName"] == MyColumnName); 
}
```

When I try it the usual way like `getOrdinal` or just `Reader["MyCustomColum"]` and try to check if it is null I get the exception IndexOutOfBounds when the column was not in the except. I know one way would be to catch the exception but that is not the way I want it, and after all I can't belive that there is no other way to check if the colum is available

Thank you

Comment: Why not to handle the exception?

Comment: As I said, i can't belive that the language does not offer any other way to do that. And the other reason is that programming where i rely on exceptions is not the style i prefer :)

Comment: Did you try to go over `Columns` collection, rather than `Rows`? Something like `Reader.GetSchemaTable()
           .Columns
           .OfType<DataColumn>()
           .Any(column => column.ColumnName == MyColumnName);`

Comment: Well, sometimes you just need to see something from a different angle :). Thanks Michael, your code put me on the right path. The thing with DataColumn did not work, but there i saw that you, just like me, do the string comparison with "==", and that is not right. After changing my code to "... row["ColumnName"].ToString().Equals(MyColumnName,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)" i got what i want. But as i said, I was looking at this for about 2 days and i did not notice that ;)

Comment: Just out of curiousity, you compare `row["ColumnName"]` or `column.ColumnName` ?

Comment: it is the same code as in my question just changed the "==" to "equals(...". I use row["ColumnName"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private bool SpalteExistiert(FbDataReader Reader, string MyColumnName) 
{
    return Reader.GetSchemaTable()
       .Rows
       .OfType<DataRow>()
       .Any(row => string.Equals(row.Field<string>("ColumnName"), MyColumnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)); 
}
```

Comment: This will still throw `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Comment: @Michael I've tried it on a SqlDataReader and it worked fine. Where exactly is the 'IndexOutOfBounds' exception thrown?

Comment: i tried this and I don't get an exception, but it always returns false. Actually you have the same error as I had. You just cast it explicitly, where in my example the cast was done at runtime but the comparison is wrong in both cases and that is the reason why you will always get "false" as result.

Comment: @user3466562 Well I've tried both with and without casting, and I did get 'true' when I used the cast. Are you sure the column you are looking for is really there?

Comment: hmm, the problem could be that I am passing the column name in lowercase and maybe you are using the exact format like it is in the database. Try writing the column name different than it is written in the DB

Comment: @user3466562 I've edited my answer: now the string comparison ignores the case. Try it and let me know :).

Comment: Now it looks good ;). You can write it even shorter when you do:... .Any( row=> row["ColumnName"].ToString().Equals(MyColumnName,StringComparison.InvariantCultu‌​reIgnoreCase));

Comment: @user3466562 Yep. Or even better using the generic method 'Field<T>':
row.Field<string>("ColumnName")

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following

```
private bool SpalteExistiert(FbDataReader Reader, string MyColumnName) 
{
    return Reader.GetSchemaTable()
       .Rows
       .OfType<DataRow>()
       .Any(row => row.Table.Columns.Contains(MyColumnName)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension method

```
    public static bool HasColumn(this IDataRecord dr, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (dr.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```